# how I can read a from taglib to <% ... %>

Tags: json, jsp, taglib

could you help please?, how I can read the variable objd in a <% ... %> Assigned in the foreach?

```
            <c:forEach var="objd" items="${beanDreqproducto}">
                <% 
                Gson j = new Gson();
                String data = j.toJson(objd);
                %>

                console.log("${objd.cantidad}, data: "+'${data}');
            </c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why would you want to? Do that work elsewhere.

Comment: I mean, you can get the variable out of the appropriate context, but ew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `${}` basically translates to [`PageContext#findAttribute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#findAttribute%28java.lang.String%29). So, this should do:

```
<%
    Object objd = pageContext.findAttribute("objd");
    // ...
%>
```

Note that you should [set](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/jsp/JspContext.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) `data` in page scope as well in order to get `${data}` to work:

```
<%
    // ...
    pageContext.setAttribute("data", data);
%>
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, this approach is ultimately bad. You should choose to use *either* JSTL/EL *or* scriptlets exclusively, not both. If you prefer JSTL/EL, just create a custom EL function to do the desired job, so that you can end up something like as follows:

```
<c:forEach var="objd" items="${beanDreqproducto}">
    console.log("${objd.cantidad}, data: ${my:toJson(objd)}");
</c:forEach>
```

Our EL wiki page contains a section how to create EL functions.

Comment: <c:forEach var="objd" items="${beanDreqproducto}">
  <% 
  Gson j = new Gson();
  Dreqproducto objd = (Dreqproducto)pageContext.findAttribute("objd");
  String data = j.toJson(objd);
  pageContext.setAttribute("data", data);
  %>
  console.log("${objd.cantidad}, data: "+'${data}');
</c:forEach>
    
thus functioning properly, but you need parse (Dreqproducto)pageContext.findAttribute("objd"); thank you very much, but please explain to me, how it works ${my:toJson(objd)} sorry, I'm new to this.
look what I'm trying to do
http://maquisac.com/upao/img.jpg